# How to find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$ using $x(\pi - x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$$ using the equation $$x(\pi - x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{\cos(2x)}{1^2}+\frac{\cos(4x)}{2^2} + \frac{\cos(6x)}{3^2} + \dotsb\right)$$

I've tried this multiple times and had no clue how to solve this

Comment: Use Parseval's identity.

Comment: Isn't double integral both side and substitute $x=0$ work?